# magento + one page check out login form is not working

Tags: php, magento, content-management-system

I used magento 1.8.1 version.
Login form is not working on one page checkout page.

login file is in template\persistent\checkout\onepage

and i also used  form key
 in login form.

but Login form is not working

please sugsest....

Comment: Have you checked log files regarding this? any console error?

Comment: Yes, I checked log files, there is no error regarding this.

Answer (score 0):

Please use following code in below location:-

```
app/design/frontend/default/[themename]/template/persistent/customer/form/login.phtml

app/design/frontend/default/[themename]/template/persistent/checkout/onepage/login.phtml
```

you will have to add a signle line.

Find  and add:

```
<input type="hidden" name="form_key" value="<? echo Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey(); ?>" />
```

I hope this helps you.

Comment: Please specify your error.what happened after you do login at the time of checkout